# Python find kmers in large lists

Tags: python, bioinformatics

How can I modify my code below to incorporate not a single string as input, but a list of strings as input?  I'm trying to find all the kmers of a list of many DNA sequences.

```
def kmer_count(dna, k):
    f = {}
    for x in range(len(dna)+1-k):
        kmer = dna[x:x+k]
        f[kmer] = f.get(kmer, 0) + 1
    return(f)
```

My input:

```
 ['GCCGGCAGCACCGGCAGCCAGGAGCCGATCGTCGCGCTGGCCGCGCTGAGCCAGGCGACGTCGGCCATCG',
 'GGCTCGTCGCGACGGTGTCGACCACGTATCACCATCCGTTTGCCGCGGCTGATCGGCACGCTCGA',
 'TCACGTGAGCGGCGGCCGCGCCCGGGGGGAACGCGGTGACGTCGTCGGTCGGCGAGGAGAATTTCGGCGAC',
 'GCCGCGTTGCCCGACCCGGAGCAGCGCTATGCGCGCGCCGCCGAATTCGTCGAAGTCGTCAACGCGCTGT',
 'TCGACGCGAACGATCCCGACGCGGTGCGACGCACGCCGAGCGGCGGCGTGTCGGAAGCT']
```

Obviously, I can't continuously assign one-by-one each string to the function `kmer_count` for practical reasons (my list is huge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple argument passing (`*args`) to pass multiple arguments to your function and use `yield` to return a generator contain all the dictionaries :

```
def kmer_count(k,*args):
  f = {}
  for dna in args: 
    for x in range(len(dna)+1-k):
        kmer = dna[x:x+k]
        f[kmer] = f.get(kmer, 0) + 1
    yield(f)
```

And if you want to get the result as a list you can use `list` to convert your iterator to a list :

```
print list(kmer_count(k,*args))
```

but as a more pythonic  way you can use `itertools.islice` and `collections,Counter` :

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import islice

def kmer_count(k,*args):
  for dna in args:
    yield Counter(''.join(islice(s,i,i+k)) for i in range(len(dna)+1-k))
```

Comment: I get this: `print kmer_count(2, record)
<generator object kmer_count at 0x106c9f2d0>` where record is the name of my list from OP

Comment: warship use print list(kmer_count(2, record))

Comment: @mmachine Then I get: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: @warship print list(kmer_count(2,'GCCGGCAGCACCGGCAGCCAGGAGCCGATCGTCGCGCTGGCCGCGCTGAGCCAGGCGACGTCGGCCATCG',
 'GGCTCGTCGCGACGGTGTCGACCACGTATCACCATCCGTTTGCCGCGGCTGATCGGCACGCTCGA',
 'TCACGTGAGCGGCGGCCGCGCCCGGGGGGAACGCGGTGACGTCGTCGGTCGGCGAGGAGAATTTCGGCGAC',
 'GCCGCGTTGCCCGACCCGGAGCAGCGCTATGCGCGCGCCGCCGAATTCGTCGAAGTCGTCAACGCGCTGT',
 'TCGACGCGAACGATCCCGACGCGGTGCGACGCACGCCGAGCGGCGGCGTGTCGGAAGCT'))